# Changing the color of value in cell based on condition in Datatables PDF

Tags: datatables, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I have a datatables table that displays student marks. When I open the table it perfectly shows the marks, if the the mark is less than 50% the mark is red in color.

However when I do the print PDF, the PDF does not change the color. Yet i want the marks to be red if they are less than 50%.

I want the marks in the PDF to be red if it is less than 50%

How do I go about adding those conditions specifically for PDF in Datatables

Comment: You can [edit] your question to provide a [mre]. Show us what you have tried, what happened when you tried it, and any errors you got. At the very least, you have a DataTable which already shows relevant values in red. Also take a look at [ask] for more general guidance.

Comment: See [How can I export the <a> tag using pdfhtml5 in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154336/12567365). This is not a solution for your _specific_ issue, but it does show you the _general_ approach for transferring custom HTML/CSS styling from a DataTable to the PDF. Use this approach, and adapt it to your needs.