# Exporting to pdf in datatables returns error in customize

Tags: datatable

I have the following code to export to pdf with datatables:

```
{
  extend: 'pdf',
  text: 'pdf',
  title: 'Registo de Marcações',
  footer: true,
    exportOptions: {
    stripHtml : false,
    columns: function ( idx, data, node ) {
      if (idx >= 4) {
        return data;
      }
    }
  },
  customize: function ( win ) {
    $(win.document.body)
    .css( 'font-size', '10pt' );
  
    $(win.document.body).find( 'table' )
    .addClass( 'compact' )
    .css( 'font-size', 'inherit' );
  }
}
```

I'll start by saying that `stripHtml: false` doesn't work, because when I generate the pdf it doesn't return the font-awesome icon. Returns as shown in the picture:

[image]

And it should return as it returns when I print:

[image]

Then in this part of the code `$(win.document.body)` generates this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'body')
> at Object.customize

How can I solve these problems? On the print button, the code works fine. The problems only appear in the generate pdf button

Comment: In your `customize: function ( win ) { ... }` code, you appear to be treating `win` as if it is some sort of HTML structure. It's actually a [pdfmake](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/) structure. You can see an example [here](https://pdfmake.github.io/docs/0.1/document-definition-object/styling/) which shows how font size (and other attributes) can be defined and altered.

Comment: Related: [How can I export the <a> tag using pdfhtml5 in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74154336/12567365). This shows an example of how DataTables can alter the pdfmake object, to control the PDF output file.

Comment: @andrewJames But in this situation it's for a link. In mine it's for `font-awesome` where the tag is `<i></i>` and I'm not getting it to work in my example

Comment: Yes, I understood that when I wrote my comments and shared that example. The example I gave is not intended to be a _specific_ solution - it's an _approach_ for how to handle the PDF document (your `win` object). That is why my comment says "related" and not "duplicate". You can apply that same approach to your specific requirement. Your approach is the reason you are getting `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined`. You are not handling your `win` object correctly.

Comment: You can investigate your `win` object by using `console.log( win );` and then drilling down into its structure, to see for yourself.