# I made a datatable with pdf and print buttons. But the images of the datatable is not visible in pdf or print view

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, datatable

I made a datatable with pdf and print buttons. But the images of the datatable is not visible in pdf or print view. I've attached logo with the data table that are visible in pdf and print view, but the existed images or fa icons are not visible.

**HTML**

```
<table id="example" class="display responsive nowrap" style="width:100%" data-page-length='3'>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
            <th>Data</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td><img src="./edit.png" class="edit-icon"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td><img src="./edit.png" class="edit-icon"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td>Data</td>
            <td><img src="./edit.png" class="edit-icon"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        dom: 'Blfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                customize: function ( doc ) {
                    doc.content.splice( 1, 0, {
                        margin: [ 0, 0, 0, 12 ],
                        alignment: 'center',
                        image: 'IMAGE DATA'
                    } );
                }
            },
            {
                extend: 'print',
                customize: function ( win ) {
                    $(win.document.body).prepend('<img src="image.png"');
                }
            },
            
            'copy', 'csv', 'excel'
        ]
        
    } );
} );
    </script>
```

**CSS**

```
@media print {
    #example {
    margin-top: 100px;
    }
    .edit-icon {
         background: url(edit.png);
         width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 5px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    display: block;
    }
}
```

**CSS Links**

```
<!-- Data Table & Data Table Buttons -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.3/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.5/css/buttons.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.6.0/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.13.2/af-2.5.2/b-2.3.4/b-html5-2.3.4/b-print-2.3.4/cr-1.6.1/date-1.3.0/fc-4.2.1/kt-2.8.1/r-2.4.0/rg-1.3.0/rr-1.3.2/sc-2.1.0/sb-1.4.0/sp-2.1.1/sl-1.6.0/sr-1.2.1/datatables.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.2/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/5.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.36/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs5/jq-3.6.0/jszip-2.5.0/dt-1.13.2/af-2.5.2/b-2.3.4/b-html5-2.3.4/b-print-2.3.4/cr-1.6.1/date-1.3.0/fc-4.2.1/kt-2.8.1/r-2.4.0/rg-1.3.0/rr-1.3.2/sc-2.1.0/sb-1.4.0/sp-2.1.1/sl-1.6.0/sr-1.2.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/css/responsive.dataTables.min.css">
```

**JS Plugins**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.13.3/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.5/js/dataTables.buttons.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.1.3/jszip.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/pdfmake.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdfmake/0.1.53/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.5/js/buttons.html5.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/buttons/2.3.5/js/buttons.print.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.4.0/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>
```

How can I print the icons/images?

HTML view of the DataTable

[image]

Comment: Some settings in your print may suppress images. What browser/OS are you running?

Comment: Windows 10 OS and Chrome, Firefox Dev Edition

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: DataTables buttons allow you to export the data loaded into the DataTable. Your icons such as `<img src="./edit.png" class="edit-icon">` are _not_ loaded into the DataTable; they are only part of the HTML table. DataTables cannot export what it does not know about.

Comment: You can take a look at [How can I export the <a> tag using pdfhtml5 in DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74153344/12567365) to get an insight into what is involved if you want to export additional data to a PDF via a DataTables button.

Answer (score 0):

pdf plugins inside can't read image from site. If you give the static url like **/usr/bla/bla**, pdf plugin able read/download it. Sometime pdf plugins able to read it, but is small case. The problem is you cant give the url like thoose on your datatables.

Other solution is, pdf are work as export outside datatable. You can use PHP or other programing to export all into pdf. Remember about the image url. You cant use **url()** to show the image. Use function to show real_path on image

For other problem, your css perhaps not loaded properly during export into PDF. Try native css when you exporting pdf.